# You can no longer quick-reply to a message after you've edited it

Tags: bug, chat

When I hover over the message of another user, I get the 3 options pictured below. The right-most of these options will make my next message a reply to the selected message:

[image]

If I decide to edit the message, the **reply** action will be gone from the options afterwards:

[image]

Comment: This is another side effect of the above mentioned question.