# When a chat post is edited by another user, it incorrectly shows the editor as the author

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

Here's this message from Sathya:

[image]

It usually shows like this in the rooms when you're in another chat room:

[image]

I edited the post to change a word repetition that sounded weird (Can you tell I'm bored and we don't have any flags in our queue?), and suddenly it changed the author to me:

[image]

What happened here?

Comment: I [asked the same thing](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/77?m=1202667#1202667), but never got a response. Then when I complained about it at a later point, Grace Note said [something along the lines](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/35?m=8284959#8284959) of what Manishearth said below.

Comment: Well, if I really had taken over the message it'd show me as the author everywhere. But this is just a bug in how the script pulls the author. When you refresh, everything's fine again.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that it does is make it hard (no message reply button) to reply to the chat message that you've edited, while the original owner can. Ditto for starring; the original owner can star it but you can't.

Basically, when you edit a message, the system treats it as yours to some degree.

IMO this isn't a major thing, as mods are the only ones who can edit the messages of others. And we do it rarely:

- To remove obscenities/PII from stuff posted by users (very rare, usually it's better to just nuke it)
- [image]
- To troll users who don't know about the fact that we can edit messages.

Comment: I never noticed the "can't reply anymore" thing (but you're right; you need to reload to fix it). Has this been reported previously?

Comment: @balpha: Doubt it. It's a really rare thing to come across. The only time this has ever annoyed me was when I was helping Grace run the Android Town Hall Chat (Dec 2012 election) by doing the janitorial insertion of message-replies for one guy who couldn't use them. And a few times when I edited a message and wanted to reply "FTFY".

Comment: @balpha: Looks like Tim Stone reported it in the chat feedback room (for the same Android THC reason): http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178156/when-a-chat-post-is-edited-by-another-user-it-incorrectly-shows-the-editor-as-t/178165?noredirect=1#comment536990_178156 (apparently works for starring as well)

Comment: @balpha http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169816/you-can-no-longer-quick-reply-to-a-message-after-youve-edited-it

Comment: @Anna Always those SU mods, abusing chat, right? :)

Comment: @slhck You said it. ;)