# Chat message edited by a different user has inconsistencies in the revision history

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, chat

<sup>*(Similar to [When a chat post is edited by another user, it incorrectly shows the editor as the author](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/178156/155739))*</sup>

---

When BoltClock modified Martinho's comment in the Lounge, [the history](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/10131054/history) lists as "Current Version" both the original author *and the original timestamp*.

This is clearly wrong!

[image: The chat message's edit history]

<sub>**PS.** Chrome's unicode support sucks, but BoltClock was probably adding a [*unicode banana*](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/index.htm), since we do so love those in the lounge.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The "current version" is exactly what is shown in the transcript. And regardless of the editing, the message was still written by R. Martinho, and is thus attributed to him, and it was still posted at 9:29. So this behavior is entirely correct.

Comment: The current version was written by BoltClock at 9:31. If this behaviour is by design, then the heading should read "As it appears in chat", not "Current version", because this segment of the post history clearly does _not_ display information about the current version.