# Editing chat message does not reflect previous edit by moderator

Tags: bug, edits, chat, moderator-tools

When a mod edits another user's chat message, it doesn't seem possible for that user to make changes to the new revision.

Steps to reproduce:

- Post a message in chat.
- Have a(nother) moderator edit that chat message.
- Try to edit that message yourself. **The text area will now contain your own last version of the message, and will not reflect the mod's edit.** It doesn't matter whether you edit via the message actions menu or via up-arrow.

The problem is fixed when reloading the page, so I guess the previous version is cached on the client side and not updated when someone else makes changes to the message.

Comment: I take it it doesn't happen when a mod edits their own post?

Comment: @Tim No it doesn't.

Comment: (very) related: [When a chat post is edited by another user, it incorrectly shows the editor as the author](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178156/when-a-chat-post-is-edited-by-another-user-it-incorrectly-shows-the-editor-as-t)